# Close Browser's storage permission popup through selenium web-driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, local-storage, user-permissions

There are some browser native popups. I want to close those through Selinium.

For example , When the application is trying to access your local storage and will ask your permission to do so.

Such popups are blocking selenium flow.

[Click here to view screen shot of the popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7FQi.png)

Comment: mahes can you please post a screenshot of the popup

Answer (score 1):

Hi please use Java Robot class to close that browser based popups

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
// now try to press tab with robot (by doing this you can make focus of your control )
// then simply click with the help of robot

// for robot methods please check this link
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I'm looking for! To dismiss (allow) the file access popup, I have tried tons of ways, e.g. setting Chrome options, setting pref in Chrome experimental options, mocking clicks using openqa Selenium, etc. But none of them working so far... By keyPress and keyRelease of the "TAB" "TAB" "ENTER", it's working as expected!

Comment: When I use tab in my chrome browser manually, it does not ever put the focus onto the permission alert. Not sure if this method works anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Use the code snippet:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

Comment: Not working for me. It throws an error : "An exception occurred: org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException". Its not a JavaScript alert. Popup coming from browser address bar for requesting user permissions to store files on the device.